# Como chamar uma ação de plugin pelo cronjobs

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou precisando executar um hook que desenvolvi dentro de um plugin em intervalos de 3 horas, eu gostaria de poder chamar esse comando em um arquivo externo parra assim adicionar no cron do servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Oi, Victor.

Para esses casos eu uso o plugin [WP Cron Control](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cron-control/). Uma solução simples sem ter que re-inventar a roda.

Espero que ajude.